# Zookeeper URL to determine Available Solr Node

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, solrcloud

I am setting up Solr Cloud (3 Solr node ) with external Zookeeper and I need to expose zookeeper URL to end user , so that zookeeper can automatically determine available sole node and return it to end user.

Does anyone know if this is feasible in Solr ? This is required for High Availability support as if one of Solr node goes down then end user should be automatically redirected to another instance of Solr.

Thanks
Shashi